# Webpack - Getting no errors but webpack.config.js is not outputting a bundle.js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I am following a simple react app tutorial and have ran into an issue with creating a `bundle.js` file with Babel and Webpack. My terminal is not showing any errors, but the `bundle.js` file is not being created and sent to `/src/static/js/`

Here is the `webpack.config.js` file:

```
"use strict";

const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'app-client.js'),
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'static', 'js'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
      loader: ['babel-loader'],
      query: {
        cacheDirectory: 'babel_cache',
        presets: ['react', 'es2015']
      }
    }]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV)
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: { warnings: false },
      mangle: true,
      sourcemap: false,
      beautify: false,
      dead_code: true
    })
  ]
};
```

These are the dependencies I currently have installed in case there is a package I am missing:

```
    "dependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "ejs": "^2.5.7",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-router": "^4.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "http-server": "^0.11.1",
    "webpack": "^3.10.0"
  }
```

The tutorial has you run the following command in the Terminal:

```
NODE_ENV=production node_modules/.bin/webpack -p
```

There is no explanation for this command, so I am not too sure what all it is doing.

Comment: bundle will not show up in your file system if you are using development environment. because webpack keeps everything in the  memory when serving from dev server. this makes it fast , and hot reloading possible. try production build and you will see the bundle

Comment: You need to use `module.rules` instead of `module.loaders` as the latter was changed to the former between versions 1 and 2.

Comment: You'll find your file in `/dist/static/js/bundle.js`.